# Object keeps Moving Up And Down Without Clicking A Button Unity How To Fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/edd418f7a7dc8716b3626dc490a1b205) first time you click the pause everythings fine but when you click the exit it will go up and , it will keep going up and down by itself. I'm not sure how I could fix this

first of I check if we clicked the pause button then it should bring my menu down it works good
then after that I check if we clicked the exit button it goes up then it starts keepign going down and up without checking for button clicks

```
    void Update()
    {

                

    

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("pausebutton"))
        {
            if (nors == true && !nors == false)
            {
                UpDown = 1;
                transform.Translate(Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
 

            if (ani == true)
            {
                darkin.SetBool("play", true);
                darkengame.SetActive(true);

            }
        }
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("exit"))
        {
            if (nors == false && !nors == true)
            {
                UpDown = 2;
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            ani = false;
            darkin.SetBool("play", false);
                

        }

    }
```

on my trigger I have it so if the menu collides with the ***stophome*** then it should stop moving up and set the ***nors to false*** and for the second collision if nors is equal to false and we click the exit menu button then it should take our menu back up and then after that it will start looping up and down and will not check if we clicked any button is there a way to fix this problem.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {




        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("stophome"))
        {

            Debug.Log(UpDown);
            nors = false;




        }
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("stophome2"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Touched");
            nors = true;




            Debug.Log(UpDown);
            darkengame.SetActive(false);


        }

        //Debug.Log("WOOW sTART IS TRUE");
    }
```

Comment: `if (nors == true && !nors == false)` - uhh.... why not just `if (nors)`?

Comment: if I do that it will continue to fall without stopping

Comment: No it won't. You're wrong. If it does, it's not down to your bizarre use of boolean values or lack thereof.

Comment: Understand that you're not changing the value of `nors` here, so if `nors == true` then `!nors == false` will also always be true.

Comment: is there a way you could show me an example that works I just did that and it will just fall down I think I'm doing something wrong I'm not sure

Comment: ok my bad I had the collision off but testing your method right now

Comment: ok so if I do that then it will continue to make the settings menu keep going up without stopping

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand enough about Unity to help with that. I was just really perplexed by your if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem should appear in CrossPlatformInputManager. GetButton should be a click event, Its response time should be only one frame.

And the use of collision to detect is not accurate, and will consume more performance

I wrote a demo I hope it can help you :)

[image]

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Record whether the UI is moving
    /// </summary>
    bool m_isPauseMenuMoving = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// Menu status
    /// </summary>
    bool m_showPasueMenu = false;    
    float m_speed = 300f;
    float m_offset = 100f; // UI height

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        //if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("pausebutton"))
        {
            if (!m_isPauseMenuMoving)
            {
                m_showPasueMenu = true;
                m_isPauseMenuMoving = true;
            }           
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        //if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("exit"))
        {
            if (!m_isPauseMenuMoving)
            {
                m_showPasueMenu = false;
                m_isPauseMenuMoving = true;
            }
        }

        if (m_isPauseMenuMoving)
        {
            var direction = m_showPasueMenu ? Vector3.down : Vector3.up;
            transform.Translate(direction * m_speed * Time.deltaTime);

            if (m_showPasueMenu)
            {
                if (transform.localPosition.y <= 0) /*A position mid of the screen (Use Screen.height, 0 is the best solution)*/
                    m_isPauseMenuMoving = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (transform.localPosition.y >= Screen.height / 2 + m_offset) /*A position top of the screen (Use Screen.height)*/
                    m_isPauseMenuMoving = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: for some reason it will continu to move it down it wont stop

Comment: To make sure that no other scripts interfere with this UI. you can test this script with an empty scene.